# Stranding of preposition in questions

Tags: prepositions

I know that in sentences such as the following one, "from" is to be put at the end of the question:

> Where are you ***from***?

Does this rule apply also to the next one:

> Which movie is this scene taken ***from***?

or should I rather use:

> ***From*** which movie is this scene taken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your versions are fine.

*Which movie is this scene taken from?* is much more commonly heard.

*From which movie is this scene taken?*  is rather formal-sounding.